# what is the right symbol for the "max" like Pi is for product?

Tags: notation

I have a set of variables that have a value, and i want to find the max of those values.

Here is the equivalent of what I want to do with "sum"

$$\sum_{j:~N_j \in U_i}~ DA_j$$

For all j subject to $N_j \in U_i$, then sum $DA_j$.  Except I want a max.  What is the right symbol to use?

Comment: I just use $\max$. Are you sure the maximum exists, though? Perhaps you should use $\sup$ instead (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supremum).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are interested of the maximum value of $DA_j$ under the condition that $N_j \in U_i$ then you can use $\max$ as in: $$\max_{j : N_j \in U_i} DA_j$$
But if you are interested in the value of $j$ that makes $DA_j$ maximal, then you can use $\operatorname{argmax}$ as in: $$\operatorname{argmax}_{j : N_j \in U_i} DA_j$$

Comment: Personally I've never heard of argmax before.

Comment: I have seen it a lot in (computer science) optimization classes. The context of optimization & searching makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 13):

Some people write
$$\bigvee_{j : N_j \in U_i} D A_j$$
with $\bigwedge$ for min.  I'm not convinced it's clearer than $\max$.  (The infix usage is more common, and more elegant looking: $a \vee b$ versus $\max\{a,b\}$.)

Comment: For me this would mean the supremum.

Comment: I only saw this in a boolean lattice context.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: That's possible.  I may have only seen it used for the maximum over a finite set.

Comment: @NateEldredge Why on earth does `max` point downwards??

Comment: @viyps: Fair question.  AFAIK they're meant to be analogous with $\cup$ and $\cap$ for union and intersection, and likewise $\vee$ and $\wedge$ for logical OR and AND.  Note, for instance, that the maximum of two Boolean values is the same as their logical OR; and that given two sets, one of which is contained in the other, the cardinality of their union is the maximum of their cardinalities.

Answer (score 2):

\max which looks like "$\max$"  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Commands